# Using __repr__() on a ctypes subclass?

Tags: python, ctypes

I am playing around with ctypes a little bit to massage some C code I wrote into Python.  The C code relies heavily on structs and unions, and for now, the quick solution in Python is to subclass those via ctypes:

I.e., from this:

```
struct foo {
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b;
    uint16_t c;
    uint16_t d;
};
```

To this:

```
from ctypes import *

class Foo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a", c_uint),
                ("b", c_uint),
                ("c", c_ushort),
                ("d", c_ushort)]
```

Except, if I toss a `__repr__()` definition into the Python class and then use `repr()` on an instance, all I get back is `<class 'Foo'>` (or something to that effect, recalling from memory a bit here).

So I am wondering if there is a way to utilize `repr()` and try to get the best of both worlds between Python and C, or if I should look at metaclasses and using the `struct` library for packing/unpacking bytes into proper Python classes.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand the problem.
This works just fine:

```
from ctypes import *

class Foo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a", c_uint),
                ("b", c_uint),
                ("c", c_ushort),
                ("d", c_ushort)]

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Foo: a:%d b:%d c:%d e:%d>" % (self.a, self.b, self.c, self.d)

f = Foo(1,2,3,4)
print repr(f)

# <Foo: a:1 b:2 c:3 e:4>
```

only if you do:

```
print repr(Foo)
```

you'll end up with

```
<class '__main__.Foo'>
```

or something similar.

Are your sure you use `repr` on an instance?

Comment: Well, I am doing this on Python 2.4, after manually building ctypes for it.  Might that be part of the problem?

Comment: Somehow I find that unlikely, I just [`tried it`](http://pastie.org/3952521) on a server with python2.4 and it worked.

Comment: Okay, chalk this one up to PEBKAC or PICNIC.  I was doing `f=Foo`, NOT `f=Foo()`.  Herp derp.